# List edition only if higher than 1st and location behind publisher

Tags: biblatex

I am trying to customize biblatex to the needs of the requirements. At this point I am working on the `book`-class.

The status quo is based on the MWE below. As I indicated in the title, I would like to have it like this:

> **Smith, J. (2012):**
>   The Random Booktitle, 3rd ed., Springer, Berlin.

Or if the edition were the 1st edition:

> **Smith, J. (2012):**
>   The Random Booktitle, Springer, Berlin.

[I tried to use the `\newbibmacro` command as suggested](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110767/biblatex-comma-with-space-behind-every-unit-style-authoryear/110810?noredirect=1#comment243873_110810), but I am pretty much just doing some t&e runs at the whole thing. So far I got this:

```
\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location}{%
\iflistundef{publisher}
{\setunit*{\addspace}}
{\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}
\printlist{publisher}
\setunit*{\addcomma\space}
\printlist{location}
\newunit}
```

I think I could add some stuff for the edition to this macro, but there would be no use to it. It rather "destroys" what I've achieved so far.

[**Please click here for a MWE.**](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5647063/)

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Ok, did it. I just edited the opening post.

Comment: Let's start with an advice: If you want to change all title you can use the star version of `\DeclareFieldFormat`. : `\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1}`. Next: The first mandatory argument of `\DeclareFieldFormat` doesn't accept a list. So `\DeclareFieldFormat{booktitle,journaltitle,i...` is wrong. With this knowledge please reduce your MWE.

Comment: Ok, [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5645683/) is an updated MWE.

Comment: You may get more and more helpful answers if you (1) try to condense your MWE down to something that **only** shows the point you are concerned with and (2) stick quite strictly to one question per question.

Comment: You're right. Should've cut it way down from the start on. So I edited my op again, I guess it should be enough this time. It actually still contains both issues only because I added `edition={1}`. I'd happy to receive an answer for either one.

Comment: As of right now, Paul Stanley solved the issue with the order of the location and publisher, so the suppression of the 1st edition is the remaining one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I get the impression that you are attempting to make rather extensive changes to the standard `authoryear` style. Can I focus on the problem you raise as the most immediate, which is the publisher and location point.

You were basically on the right track. The relevant macro is actually called `publisher+location+date` (though, for reasons that don't matter now, it doesn't end up printing the date in the `authoryear` style. Your redefinition would basically work, but (since you've already redefined the `\newunitpunct`) you can make it still simpler

```
\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
\newunit
\printlist{publisher}%
\newunit
\printlist{location}%
\newunit}
```

As far as your **edition** point is concerned, the edition is handled considerably earlier in the driver -- it usually follows the title. I suspect that this is really what you want (it will, in the ordinary case, mean that the edition is followed by publisher and location). If you want to move it so that it is always handled immediately before the publisher you will need to rewrite drivers. But please find an example with reasonable data that is printing the edition **wrong** before trying that, because I suspect there is actually no problem.

---

**UPDATE**

As to not printing of the edition if it is "1", the following redefinition of the field format will do it, I think. Note that it **only** "catches" (and does not print) the precise "1": "1st" or "First" would be printed.

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{edition}{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{1}
     {}
     {\ifinteger{#1}
       {\mkbibordedition{#1}~\bibstring{edition}}
       {#1\isdot}}}
```

But please think again about this! Granted it is not normally the practice to include the edition information in the `.bib` file if the edition is the first. But if such information *is* included, why should it not be printed? What will happen if you/your user wishes to cite both the first and the second edition of a particular work?

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked. Also, thanks for the little additional note to *not* worry about the inclusion of date in the macro. About the edition being printed, see the new MWE in the op please. I set the edition value to 1 and it is being printed.

Comment: In regards to your update: I am just trying to fulfill some very specific requirements, so... although I see your point, I can of course just check that there are no entries for the edition if it is the first. I reckon it is easier this way rather than to code it? But ever since I tested my mwe I saw it is printing ordinal numbers which I want to use anyway. So it's ok, I'll be leaving the info out because of the requirement.